# Does google news sitemap needs to be included in robots.txt

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, google-news

I've read the guideline on google news sitemap but could not locate whether google news sitemap needs to be referenced on robots.txt.

https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/74288?hl=en#sitemapguidelines

Could someone please confirm

Answer (score 0):

On the documentation page you linked, there is this note:

> Once you've created your Sitemap, upload it to the highest-level directory that contains your news articles. Please see [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183669) for further instructions on submitting your Sitemap.

It explains that you can submit the sitemaps in *Google Webmaster Tools*: <kbd>Crawl</kbd> → <kbd>Sitemaps</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

No it does not need to be included in `robots.txt` if you have submitted it to Google, but it is a good practice to do so.